# Running MySQL with on different directory

Tags: mysql

### GOAL:

I am trying to run mysql on my work servers machines. But as admins did not install it in the usual default installation path, it fails. How can I make it works?

### FACTS:

MySQL is installed under: `/opt/mysql/10.1.16/`

```
$> ls -1 /opt/mysql/10.1.16/
bin
COPYING
COPYING.LESSER
COPYING.thirdparty
CREDITS
data
EXCEPTIONS-CLIENT
include
INSTALL-BINARY
lib
man
mysql-test
README
README-wsrep
scripts
share
sql-bench
support-files
```

However, when I want to run mysql from a script, I do:

```
export LIBMYSQL_PLUGIN_DIR="/opt/mysql/10.1.16/lib/plugin"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/mysql/10.1.16/lib"
export LD_RUN_PATH="/opt/mysql/10.1.16/lib"
export PATH="/opt/mysql/10.1.16/bin:/home/xxxxxxxx/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/lib64/jvm/jre/bin:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin"

/opt/mysql/10.1.16/bin/mysql -C --no-beep --line-numbers --protocol=TCP --host="${DB_HOSTNAME}" --port="${DB_PORT}" --user="${DB_USER}" --database "${DB_SCHEMA}" -o --delimiter ','
```

With all my `DB_xxxx` corectly set, I get the following error:

`ERROR 2059 (HY000): Authentication plugin 'dialog' cannot be loaded: /usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/dialog.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I checked the official documentation page:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/environment-variables.html and the only mention about plugin is to check if `LIBMYSQL_PLUGIN_DIR`, which seems good since:

```
$> echo "${LIBMYSQL_PLUGIN_DIR}"
/opt/mysql/10.1.16/lib/plugin

$> ls -la /opt/mysql/10.1.16/lib/plugin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba    17382 Sep 13  2016 adt_null.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba    12462 Sep 13  2016 auth_0x0100.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba    33039 Sep 13  2016 auth_gssapi_client.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba    80774 Sep 13  2016 auth_gssapi.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba    18007 Sep 13  2016 auth_pam.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba    13028 Sep 13  2016 auth_socket.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba    23521 Sep 13  2016 auth_test_plugin.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql dba      227 Sep 13  2016 daemon_example.ini
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba    15267 Sep 13  2016 debug_key_management.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba    14975 Sep 13  2016 dialog_examples.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba    39102 Sep 13  2016 dialog.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba    35337 Sep 13  2016 example_key_management.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba    67516 Sep 13  2016 file_key_management.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba   534847 Sep 13  2016 ha_archive.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba   326244 Sep 13  2016 ha_blackhole.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba  6315641 Sep 13  2016 ha_connect.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba   270829 Sep 13  2016 ha_example.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba   408688 Sep 13  2016 ha_federated.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba   658050 Sep 13  2016 ha_federatedx.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba 17067973 Sep 13  2016 ha_innodb.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba 13007344 Sep 13  2016 ha_mroonga.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba  1586135 Sep 13  2016 handlersocket.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba  1687004 Sep 13  2016 ha_oqgraph.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba   745005 Sep 13  2016 ha_sphinx.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba  5150095 Sep 13  2016 ha_spider.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba   226800 Sep 13  2016 ha_test_sql_discovery.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba    35898 Sep 13  2016 libdaemon_example.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba   131020 Sep 13  2016 locales.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba   221483 Sep 13  2016 metadata_lock_info.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba    18211 Sep 13  2016 mypluglib.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba    16382 Sep 13  2016 mysql_clear_password.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba    18751 Sep 13  2016 qa_auth_client.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba    24478 Sep 13  2016 qa_auth_interface.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba    13542 Sep 13  2016 qa_auth_server.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba   229059 Sep 13  2016 query_cache_info.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba   286720 Sep 13  2016 query_response_time.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba   534415 Sep 13  2016 semisync_master.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba   445144 Sep 13  2016 semisync_slave.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba   175928 Sep 13  2016 server_audit.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba    32295 Sep 13  2016 simple_password_check.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba    19846 Sep 13  2016 sql_errlog.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql dba   218688 Sep 13  2016 wsrep_info.so
```

All libraries have execution rights, they are all here BUT MYSQL is still trying to search in the default path `/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/`. And of course on our machine, this path does not exist.

### QUESTION:

Is there another option/way to specifically ask mysql to load plugin for a specific directory?

### NOTES:

I found some links about the error `ERROR 2059 (HY000): Authentication plugin 'dialog' cannot be loaded: /usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/dialog.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` but solutions are all:

- Uninstall mysql and install it again (which I can't)
- Create the directory or symlink (I can't neither)
- Use the `--enable-cleartext-plugin` option (it does nothing and I don't think it is related in my case)

Comment: Add `--defaults-file=` option with proper value into the command line. Ensure that `datadir` is correctly set in this file.

Comment: ``/opt/mysql/10.1.16/bin/mysql: unknown option '--defaults-file'``

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_defaults-file From the other side `10.1.16` makes me think that you are using MariaDB... which have this command-line option too: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql-command-line-client/#options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I understood why.

Setting LIBMYSQL_PLUGIN_DIR:

`export LIBMYSQL_PLUGIN_DIR="/opt/mysql/10.1.16/lib/plugin"`

is somehow not read or taken in account.

---

However, adding directly to the binary the option `--plugin-dir="${LIBMYSQL_PLUGIN_DIR}"` will make it work.

So correct answer is:

```
/opt/mysql/10.1.16/bin/mysql --plugin-dir="${LIBMYSQL_PLUGIN_DIR}" -C --no-beep --line-numbers --protocol=TCP --host="${DB_HOSTNAME}" --port="${DB_PORT}" --user="${DB_USER}" --database "${DB_SCHEMA}" -o --delimiter ','
```

Why the env varibale is not read, that is a mystery